# How do I tell my Elastic Beanstalk instance not to go to sleep?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, iis, asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've setup an Elastic Beanstalk instance on the .NET (Windows/IIS) platform.  I've deployed a .NET Core application there that does 2 things:

1. Respond with Hello world! when I hit the end point - but I don't care about that.
2. Sets up a listener for RabbitMQ (also hosted in AWS). This listener fires off an SMS every time I drop some a message in RabbitMQ.

Item 2 works great - I drop off a message and less than a second later I get an SMS message on my phone.

The problem is that AWS puts the application to sleep after a period of inactivity.  And that causes the RabbitMQ listener to also go to sleep.  This results in undelivered SMS messages.  Until I wake up the instance by going to the URL assigned to my by Elastic Beanstalk.

How do I make my Elastic Beanstalk instance not go to sleep? Is there something I can call from C# code to prevent it from doing so?

Comment: AWS does not put Elastic Beanstalk applications to sleep due to inactivity. It sounds like your application isn't configured correctly somehow. You should be searching for what generally causes this behavior in a C#/IIS environment, it is not being caused by AWS/Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: @MarkB IIS environment outside of AWS will, by default, put an app to sleep if unused.  But it's trival to change it in the IIS settings.  In the Elastic Beanstalk I don't see any controls to do that.  There isn't any interface to do, unless I am missing something basic.

Comment: You would use the techniques described on this page to modify that setting http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html#windows-services

Comment: @AngryHacker did you find a solution on how to configure the IIS server through Elastic BeanStalk?

Comment: @dyesdyes No.  There might be a way, but I moved on to a different solution.

Comment: You can casually give him a double shot black coffee :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I implemented following [this article](https://notebookheavy.com/2017/06/21/set-iis-idle-timeout-elastic-beanstalk/).

1. Create a .ebextensions folder at the root of your api/web project.
2. In this project, any .config file will be used as config for your elastic beanstalk, they will be applied in alphabetical order. So create a file containing the following : (see in the link, the white space is important and I can't seem to get it right here...)

   commands:
       setIdleTimeoutToZero:
           cwd: "C:\windows\system32\inetsrv"
           command: "appcmd set apppool /apppool.name:DefaultAppPool /.processModel.idleTimeout:0.00:00:00"
3. Make sure the file is always copied to output.
4. You should be good to go.